# nginx cakephp rewrite rules suddenly causing 404, it was working before

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have cakephp set up with nginx, and before I had nginx set up and url rewriting was working perfectly, such that urls of form: `mywebsite.com/cake_project/controller/action` worked perfectly. Then I changed the name of the folder `cake_project` to `web`, and updated the nginx config file and now when I go to `mywebsite.com/web` the cakephp works, but If I go to `mywebsite.com/web/controller` or `mywebsite.com/web/controller/action` it gives 404.

(My Operating system is Ubuntu, and my CakePHP version is 2.3.9)

Here is what my current nginx config is, sorry I didn't backup my old nginx config :( (that probably would have helped me).

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mywebsite.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate path_to_ssl_certificate;
        ssl_certificate_key path_to_ssl_key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

        location /web {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/webroot;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /web/webroot/index.php;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        #location /RequestDenied {
        #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #}

        #error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        #
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#       listen 8000;
#       listen somename:8080;
#       server_name somename alias another.alias;
#       root html;
#       index index.html index.htm;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Can Anyone see, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar Nginx configs to this on everything from Nginx 1.4 - 1.8 seems to work well with CakePHP overall especially for the rewriting. Do you have things that are using the IPv6? I would think that stuff could go, if you are sure nothing is using IPv6.

Here is a working example I have working with several CakePHP 2.x project:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/production/app/webroot;
    index index.php;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl.crt/www.example.com.intermediate.combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key/www.example.com.key;

    # For Larger File Uploads
    client_max_body_size 28M;

    # This is for CakePHP
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
        break;
    }

    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    # Cache Headers for Static Files
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    # listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files no$
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        send_timeout 300;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files,
    # git & svn repositories, etc
    location ~ /\.(ht|git|svn) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Here is another option that might work for you:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate path_to_ssl_certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key path_to_ssl_key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    location /web {
        rewrite ^/web$ /web/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/web/(.+)$ /$1 break;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/webroot;
        try_files $uri /$uri/ @cakephp;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # Other PHP Files - Non-CakePHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # For CakePHP
    location @cakephp {
        set $q $request_uri;
        if ($request_uri ~ "^/web(.+)$") {
            set $q $1;
        }
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/webroot/index.php;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$q;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files no$
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```